# numpy.linalg.det of square array of mpmath.mpfs

Tags: numpy, mpmath

I am having the following issue:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import mpmath as mp
>>> v1 = [mp.mpf(1), mp.mpf(2)]
>>> v2 = [mp.mpf(3), mp.mpf(4)]
>>> np.dot(v1,v2)
mpf('11.0')
>>> M2 = [[mp.mpf(1), mp.mpf(2)], [mp.mpf(3), mp.mpf(4)]]
>>> np.linalg.det(M2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1776, in det
    r = _umath_linalg.det(a, signature=signature)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc det
```

My calls to `numpy`'s `linalg.det` method work fine with non-`mpmath` entries, yet I get the above error when giving it `mp.mpf`s. The old question [Interoperability between Numpy and MpMath in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113979/interoperability-between-numpy-and-mpmath-in-python) indicates that `np.dot` will work just fine if the entries are `mp.mpf`s (confirmed above), so my question is why this doesn't carry over to `np.linalg.det`, and what I can do to get around this. The context is that I have already written a large amount of code using only `numpy` (no `mpmath`) and only just realized I will need much higher numerical precision, so ideally there is a solution that doesn't involve converting all of the `numpy` code.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: As indicated by the link, `dot` has an branch that can work with object dtype arrays, though the speed is considerably less than with numeric dtypes.  `det` does not have that option.  It only uses compiled numeric code.  Math with object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss, and always slower.

Comment: @hpaulj Okay, so it sounds like there isn't a good workaround for `mpmath`. Is there a different library for higher numerical precision which interfaces better with `numpy` methods?

Comment: Why not use `mpmath.det`?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `mp.det` was compatible with `np.array` but I see now that it should work. Computing inverses may still be an issue (since `mpmath` treats inverses as an attribute or from `**-1`) but I can probably work around that. Thank you both for pointing me in the right direction!